# xml white space issue using c#

Tags: xml, xmltextwriter

I am creating xml file using below code problem is when there is extra spaces in sentence or content this code is converting it into single space how to handle this

```
    using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Create the writer.
        XmlTextWriter writer = null;
        writer = new XmlTextWriter("c:\\ws.html", null);

        // Write an element (this one is the root).
        writer.WriteStartElement("p");

        // Write the xml:space attribute.
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xml", "space", null, "preserve");

        // Verify that xml:space is set properly. 
        if (writer.XmlSpace == XmlSpace.Preserve)
            Console.WriteLine("xmlspace is correct!");

        // Write out the HTML elements.  Insert white space 
        // between 'something' and 'Big'
        writer.WriteString("something    extra spacess in this line but not     coming in xml    i want this extra spaces");
        writer.WriteWhitespace("  ");
        writer.WriteElementString("b", "B");
        writer.WriteString("ig");

        // Write the root end element.
        writer.WriteEndElement();

        // Write the XML to file and close the writer.
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `writer.WriteCData()`?  That will surround it with a `<![CDATA[...]]>` block that may preserve spaces (haven't tried it myself, so couldn't say).

Obviously, not great if you don't want it as a data block.

Comment: i want to add it as xmlelement for cdata it is working but not useful for me